# Unable to see gains on using boost::multi_array as compared to raw C array of pointers or C++ vector<vector<double>>

Tags: c++, c, boost, stdvector

I am running a simple benchmarking exercise of 2d array access of reading and writing.

I have `const int XDim = 1000;` and `const int YDim = 1000;` and create a `1000 x 1000` matrix.

In C-style, I initialize using

```
double* doubleArray[XDim];
for (int i = 0; i < XDim; i++)
    doubleArray[i] = (double*)malloc(YDim * sizeof(double));
for (int i = 0; i < XDim; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < YDim; j++)
        doubleArray[i][j] = 0.;
```

In C++ `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` I use:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> doubleArray;
std::vector<double> vecdbl;
for (int i = 0; i < XDim; i++)
    doubleArray.push_back(vecdbl);
for (int i = 0; i < XDim; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < YDim; j++)
        doubleArray[i].push_back(0.);
```

In boost style, I use:

```
typedef boost::multi_array<double, 2> OuterArray;
typedef boost::array<OuterArray::index, 2> OuterArrayIndices;
OuterArray::index rows = XDim;
OuterArray::index cols = YDim;
OuterArrayIndices shape = { rows, cols };
OuterArray doubleArray(shape);
for (int i = 0; i < XDim; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < YDim; j++)
        doubleArray[i][j] = 0.;
```

Then, I randomly pick `999999` elements from `doubleArray[][]` and set them to a random integer value chosen in `[-5, 5]`. Then, I further pick randomly `999999` elements, add them up, then find their avarage. The average is found and the time taken for all of this is displayed. This exercise is repeated many times.

The Godbolt link that does all this is available over [here](https://godbolt.org/z/r9rfaje5M)

On the above link, Godbolt seems to only handle `const int total_iterations = 2;`. Larger values give an error that the time has exceeded. On running this on my computer with `const int total_iterations = 100;`, a consistent pattern I observe is that the boost method is unable to match the C method of `malloc` or the C++ method of `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`. Between the latter two, mostly, the C method beats the C++ method while there are a handful of instances of the reverse. All of this is compiled and run in Visual Studio in Release mode using default settings.

I am unable to see the value of `boost::multi_array` given this over raw C pointer of pointer or `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`. Is there a way `boost::multi_array` can be made faster?

---

***Edited to add***: Based on comments, with sequential access to array elements, and release mode settings on Godbolt, `boost::multi_array` wins majority of the times. See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/jcT1a6vPa) 9 out of 10 times.

With nonsequential, random access to elements, and release mode settings on Godbolt, it is close, with C style slightly better than `boost::multi_array`. See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/aT8c6KxzM)

Thanks to tstanisl in the comments, for sequential access, C style seems to be faster in 10 out of 10 times. His link is accessible [here](https://godbolt.org/z/GY36GKP41)

There is an overall caveat pointed out by user n-m-could-be-an-ai that this profiling could be profiling the random number generator. Controlling for that seems to be beyond the purview of this question. However, it appears that regardless, since the same number of RNGs are generated for each case, and since the number of iterations is also not 1 or 2, but larger, that could be a wash. I could be wrong.

---

***Edited to add***(2): Based on answer provided by chqrlie, I have modified the code which is available [here](https://godbolt.org/z/55WE8ss4c). I have commented it hopefully sufficiently to see what is going on. It is still not fully clear to me which way is faster, but perhaps someone else can use this code as a starting point to better benchmark these various data structures.

Comment: What is aim of picking the tag C for C++ code?

Comment: @273K What do you mean C++ (only) code? There is a part of the code that is explicitly C-style in terms of malloc and free, etc. Did you get a chance to look at the Godbolt link? Furthermore, I would definitely like to use the fastest way of 2d access (in terms of reading or writing) and I am agnostic whether that comes via C style coding, or C++ or boost!

Comment: Your C-style code is a part of C++ code, it doesn't make the code C.

Comment: *"Larger values give an error that the time has exceeded. "* That's because code is compiled without optimizations. After enabling them it may execute multiple iterations. https://godbolt.org/z/h6znYaPc6 And the strongest advantage of multi array is that it is not a jagged array. So you can iterate between rows using just a single pointer or save / load all the data as a single operation.

Comment: @user7860670 Thank you! On my VS Release mode build, I somehow do not see these numbers as you have shown on Godbolt.  Let me try this on Linux WSL to see how it goes.  Iter # 0, 2, 5 and 6 in your Godbolt link , multi array does not seem to be performing that well. If access is sequential, perhaps because it is not a jagged array, the gains will be much more obvious. Let me try that as well. Your comment has been useful!

Comment: *"Release mode using default settings"* - maybe that's the problem, default settings are not that fast. It would be a good idea to tune inlining to any suitable, disable overflow guards, etc.

Comment: one thing you don't consider is memory fragmentation, the allocator is likely giving you a contegious chunk of memory for all the sub arrays in your simple example because there is nothing else in the memory, but in a real application the vector of vectors will likely be scattered across the memory and therefore slow.

Comment: You are measuring mostly the performance of your RNG.

Comment: @Tryer -- You should [try this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943621/how-to-create-a-contiguous-2d-array-in-c/21944048#21944048) instead of your method of calling `malloc`, `new`, whatever, in a loop.  As the answer in the link states, only two calls to the allocator are done in total, and also it much much easier to rollback a failed called to the allocator, unlike your `for` loop example.

Comment: @AhmedAEK It seems quite difficult to control for that. An application is always going to be running with other applications in place, no?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Quite possibly. Without this way, if I hardcode values into it, I am worried with optimizations turned on, one of the methods beats the other due to reasons other than whether the underlying data structure itself is efficient. Is there any other way we could control for RNG, in your view?

Comment: You need to generate all the random numbers outside of your timed code section.

Comment: In C you can do `double (*doubleArray)[YDim] = calloc(XDim * sizeof *doubleArray);` to dynamically allocate a true 2D array.

Comment: Actually, the allocation is a bit complex because C++ is notoriously incompatible with VLA types. The working version can be found at [link](https://godbolt.org/z/GY36GKP41). The C99 method is a clean winner.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you for the link. It seems to me that `boost::multi_array` should  be a superset of the functionality you have over at that place.  It is a non-jagged array and I would expect that in such instances, one could not do any better than `boost::multi_array`, given that it is a popular library.

Comment: What does "ETA" stand for?

Comment: @sehe "Edited to Add"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid your benchmark has serious flaws that make the results almost meaningless:

- you compile the C++ code without optimisations. Add `-O2` or `-O3` in the command option field of the compilation window after uncovering it.
- you use Godbolt's infrastructure to run the benchmark: the CPUs in the cloud are wildly overloaded, which may explain the inconsistent results between runs and even from one method to another.
- it is unclear how efficient the random number generators are compared to the matrix access times: you should use a separate array to pre-compute these values or at least measure the time without array access, summing all such computations to avoid optimisation side effects.

Here is a modified version with an additional matrix implementation using C99 VLAs, which are supported by gcc: https://godbolt.org/z/v5o8P5M6d

Try it on a standalone idle computer to get meaningful results.

Comment: Fair enough regarding my original OP. The flaws were pointed out in the comments. Please see `ETA` (edited to add section).I have tried to address these (including some useful links by other users in the comments). All I am really trying to do is to see for myself whether I should be using C style or C++ style (vec of vec of doubles) or use boost for non-jagged multi D array/matrix. Different internet/google links seem to not help in reaching a consensus one way or the other. If you are aware of any valid benchmarks for random/sequential access into such data structures, please do let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the additional dry run option and 2nd version of C style. I am using that to verify on my machine. Could you indicate what purpose the dry run achieves?

Comment: @Tryer: the *Dry run* step measures the time needed to compute the pseudo random values, assuming further computations will take similar time.

Comment: Ah, I see. So, ideally, this dry run time should be *subtracted* from the other displayed times to separate the effect of RNG vs array access. Good idea!

Comment: @Tryer: note also that the RNG should be reset between tests to generate the same sequence for all methods, otherwise you are comparing different access patterns that may be subtly biassed. It also seems unnecessary to use random numbers for the values stored in the array, but it may be a good test to check that the RNG generates the same sequence.

Comment: @chqrlie I was late to the party, but dropped my $0.02 as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/77150853/85371

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't expect to see much gains as the access patterns don't afford much gains.

However you can separate the scenario building from the perf measurements, and then do that properly, so you get:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/4os7hza8M)**

```
#define NDEBUG
#define BOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS 1
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

template <typename F, typename... Args>
auto timed(std::string_view caption, F f, Args const&... args) {
    using C = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    struct Report {
        std::string_view caption;
        C::time_point    s;
        ~Report() { std::cout << caption << ": " << (C::now() - s) / 1.s << "s\n"; }
    } r{caption, C::now()};

    return f(args...);
}

static size_t constexpr XDim             = 1'000;
static size_t constexpr YDim             = 1'000;
static size_t constexpr total_iterations = 2;
static size_t constexpr nsamples         = 999'999;
using Value                              = int;

namespace Generate {
    static std::mt19937                            rng{std::random_device{}()}; // or handpick a seed?
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<Value>    pm5{-5, 5};
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned> genX{0, XDim - 1}, genY{0, YDim - 1};
    using Value = int;
    struct Scenario {
        struct {
            unsigned x = genX(rng), y = genY(rng);
            Value    val = pm5(rng);
        } data[nsamples];
        struct {
            unsigned x = genX(rng), y = genY(rng);
        } probes[nsamples];
    };
} // namespace Generate

template <typename Array>
void RunScenario(Generate::Scenario const& scenario, Array&& arr) {
    for (auto [x, y, val] : scenario.data)
        arr[x][y] = val;
    double sum = 0;
    for (auto [x, y] : scenario.probes)
        sum += arr[x][y];
    printf("Average is %.4f\t", sum / nsamples);
}

static inline void c_style(Generate::Scenario const& scenario) {
    double* arr[XDim];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < XDim; i++)
        arr[i] = (double*)malloc(YDim * sizeof(double));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < XDim; i++)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < YDim; j++)
            arr[i][j] = 0.;

    RunScenario(scenario, arr);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < XDim; i++)
        free(arr[i]);
};

static inline void cxx_style(Generate::Scenario const& scenario) {
    using Row = std::vector<double>;
    std::vector<Row> arr(XDim, Row(YDim, 0.));

    RunScenario(scenario, arr);
};

static inline void multi_array_style(Generate::Scenario const& scenario) {
    using Array = boost::multi_array<double, 2>;
    static constexpr std::array<Array::index, 2> shape{XDim, YDim};

    Array arr(shape);
    RunScenario(scenario, arr);
};

int main() {
    /*
     * In each iteration, we will populate 999'999 randomly chosen entries of
     * the 1000 x 1000 array of doubles with random integer entries between
     * [-5, 5]
     *
     * Then, we will find the average of 999'999 randomly chosen entries of the
     * 1000 x 1000 array of doubles by summing them up and dividing by 999'999
     */
    for (size_t iteration = 0; iteration < total_iterations; ++iteration) {
        std::cout << "\n----Iteration " << iteration << "----\n";

        auto scenario = timed("New scenario", []{ return std::make_unique<Generate::Scenario>(); });

        timed("C          style", c_style,           *scenario);
        timed("C++        style", cxx_style,         *scenario);
        timed("MultiArray style", multi_array_style, *scenario);
    }
}
```

The output being something like

```
----Iteration 0----
New scenario: 0.0425284s
Average is 0.0018   C          style: 0.0152797s
Average is 0.0018   C++        style: 0.0143449s
Average is 0.0018   MultiArray style: 0.0135915s

----Iteration 1----
New scenario: 0.0393743s
Average is -0.0007  C          style: 0.0138404s
Average is -0.0007  C++        style: 0.0107113s
Average is -0.0007  MultiArray style: 0.00985549s
```

[image]

Comment: I have been able to get the code to compile on my machine and based on preliminary tests, it does not appear that one method dominates the other clearly. when you say access patterns don't afford much gains, I do not understand why so. We are doing a completely random access of elements in a large 2d array. So, I would expect that cache-locality, etc., are not available. Do you mean that access patterns being so random mean that all 3 ways perform equally badly or equally good? Could you suggest an access pattern where  `boost::multi_array` is clearly better ?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly it. Try summing all the values. That will change the equation: https://godbolt.org/z/sEq3hxaax Local timings: https://i.imgur.com/PgIJ2DE.mp4 (note that you can spell it `std::accumulate(arr.origin(), arr.origin()+arr.num_elements(), 0.0)` for the multi_array, possibly quicker)

Comment: I see. So, a linear sequential access is best for `boost::multi_array` to shine. Last Q, would you have any suggestion for a jagged array where the last dimension need not be of the same size for each ? I cannot think of anything other than `vector<vector<T>>` where the inner `vector<T>` has different sizes for different indices of the outer `vector`.

Comment: Do you have applications for this? Because it seems to me you'd usually have some way of knowing how many elements are in each "row". There are many common approaches for sparse matrix representation. See e.g. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix_sparse.html. At this point I'm starting to think the question might be [X/Y Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) and you really don't need to squeeze 5% more performance out of a pre-ordained datastructure, rather than design the right datastructure for the algorithms that might save a lot more.

Comment: I do have many applications. In writing separation routines for integer programs, one encounters situatons where in each iteration, the set of customers (say, could be 1000 in total) in number, could align themselves randomly over the outer indices (which could represent shops they visit). So, if there are 3 shops (outer indices), customers could be 333, 333, 334 (total 1000) or else align themselves 100, 0, 900. So, a 3 x 1000 matrix would be highly wasteful. I will look into sparse matrix library. As of now, I  have gotten by by using vector<vector<T>>

Comment: So, I can have, `std::vector<std::vector<int>> Shops_Customers;` Then, to access all customers visiting the 2nd shop, I would access, the `std::vector<int>` at the index 1: `Shops_Customers[1]` In the next iteration, after I add some inequalities, the customers visiting each shop could change completely differently as specified in my previous comment (333, 333, 334 vs 100, 0, 900)

Comment: This sounds like you're not looking for matrices at all. It sounds more like graphs, or different indexes across the same entity. But certainly do look at the sparse matrix representation - they could even be used to model graph adjacencies efficiently

Comment: a question: https://github.com/boostorg/assert/blob/develop/include/boost/assert.hpp#L36 is this the reason why you have `NDEBUG` and `BOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS` at the very top? i.e., are these for obtaining "release mode" fastest boost performance? Are there any other preprocessor macros that need to be defined to obtain "release mode" performance?

Comment: I just meant to be explicit and independent of build configuration/tooling. You would usually NOT define those two: instead you would just "ask" Release mode in your build tool and get both for free.

Comment: And this is the reason why it matters: [By default, both of the above element access methods perform range checking. If a supplied index is out of the range defined for an array, an assertion will abort the program. To disable range checking (for performance reasons in production releases), define the BOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS preprocessor macro prior to including multi_array.hpp in your application.)](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html#sec_access)

Comment: `NDEBUG` sure is for free in Visual Studio IDE under default Release mode setting, but `BOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS` has to be explicitly set in the IDE. Unless of course, `BOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS` is implied by `NDEBUG` somewhere within boost code ibraries. On GCC, perhaps `/O2` implies `NDEBUG`?

Comment: NDEBUG does imply BOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/assert/assert.html

Comment: Thanks for providing me what that. I will store it for future reference. However, I do not see how you have concluded so. The docs say: `If the macro BOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS is defined when <boost/assert.hpp> is included, BOOST_ASSERT(expr) expands to ((void)0), regardless of whether the macro NDEBUG is defined. This allows users to selectively disable BOOST_ASSERT without affecting the definition of the standard assert.` Unless I miss something, nowhere does it say `NDEBUG ==> BOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS`. They seem to be independent. Perhaps you meant `does not imply` ?

Comment: You need to read the whole section. It lists a number of different explicit configurations and ends up describing the default behavior if none of those are present.